# Search next button javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, search

Is there any possible way to create a search next and a search all button with javascript? This is my script so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd)
    {
        input.focus();
        input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
    function selectString (input, string)
    {
        var match = new RegExp(string, "g").exec(input.value);
        if (match)
    {
    setSelectionRange (input, match.index, match.index + match[0].length);
    }
    }
</script>
```

```
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="selectString(document.getElementById('text'), document.getElementById('search').value);return false;">               
        <legend>
            <font face="verdana">Zoekveld</font face>
        </legend>
        <input id="search" name="search" type="text" size="75">
        <input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
</form>

<form name=form1 method="get">
        <legend>
            <font face="Verdana">Vind:</font face>
        </legend>
        <textarea id="text" cols="54" rows="20"></textarea>
</form>
```

The problem with this script is that it can only find the first match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the RegExp in a variable instead of creating a new one each function execution and it's counter property [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) for `exec()` will persist.

```
var r = /^$/;
function setSelector(string) {
    r = new RegExp(string, "i");
}
function selectNextMatch(input) {
    var match = r.exec(input.value);
    if (match)
        setSelectionRange(...);
    else
        alert("Nothing found");
}
```

```
<input type="text" size="75" onchange="setSelector(this.value);">
<input type="button" value="Zoeken" onclick="selectNextMatch(document.getElementById('text'));">
<textarea id="text" cols="54" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: So if I just change it into:
var match = new RegExp(string, "i").lastIndex(input.value);
it should work?

But it doesn't :( sorry for being such a noob in javascript... (Could you possibly change my script for me... Or tell me how to do it or where I could get a tutorial or something?)

Comment: I've added an example. I'm not sure *when* you are trying to find the other matches, the script depends on that.

Comment: Oke i will try to change my code. And I'm trying to find all matches at once. Thx for the help so far :)

Comment: Please post code only in your question, you can edit it and append formatted sources.

Comment: I've added the html in my answer.

Comment: Thx for the help!!! Is there's anything I could do to repay you just say the price :)

Comment: @user1339469: Share your knowledge. You could start with answering my [open question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423153/ie7-8-floating-or-clearing-bugs)(s) :-)

Comment: Could you just do me one more little favor? Could you explain to me which Javascript does what :s

Comment: Is there a way where i can get all searchresults in one time?

Comment: You can add the "g" flag for global search, which will return all results as an array. But I don't think you can hightlight multiple ranges in a textarea.